# SB@ in dtx and sty files

Tags: packages, dtx

When reading several dtx files in order to write my own, I saw the command `\SB@...` in front of several other commands. What does it mean? I could not find reliable sources as explanation.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do (there are others about the use of `@`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not *in front* of the command it is part of the command, in packages `@` is a letter so `\SB@foobar` is just the command with name `\SB@foobar` package authors often use such a naming scheme to avoid clashes with other packages.

In this case the `songs` package author has used this naming scheme

```
 \def\SB@star...
```

so `\SB@star` could have been called `\zzzstar` the `@` has no special role here other than for example all `longtable` package internals are called `\LT@...` so the chance of two packages clashing is reduced.